# How Do I Deal With This C++ Multimap Issue?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers

I am a beginner in C++ working on simple program and I ran into an issue which left me stumped... Basically I created a multimap that accepts a part of string person name and a pointer to a person object.

So My first function to work with was the "Add()" function. I basically construct a new person with a name and age and then set a pointer to that object. Then I insert the name and the object into the multimap as a pair.

The problem happens when I run the find() function... My output only gives me a valid name but for the age I get what seems like a truncated memory address or a random number? Since i'm a beginner I am pretty sure I am doing something very simple yet very stupid. I don't think you will need to run the code since it's so simple. All help is appreciated. Thank you!

## My runnable file:

```
#include "Person.h"
#include <map>
using namespace std;

multimap<string, Person*> personMap;
multimap<string, Person*>::iterator counter;


void add()
{
  string name;
  int age;
  cout << "Please enter the name of the person: ",  cin >> name;
  cout << "Please enter the age of the person: ", cin >> age;
  Person generatedPerson(name, age);

  // Avoid dynamic class pointers for memory optimization.
  // Avoided: Person* pointer = new Person(name, age).
  Person *pointer = &generatedPerson;
  personMap.insert({name, pointer});

}

void find()
{
  string personToBeFound;
  cout << "Who do you wish to find, friend: ", cin >> personToBeFound;


  for (counter = personMap.begin(); counter != personMap.end(); counter++)
  {
    if (counter->first == personToBeFound)
    {
      cout << "\nName: " << counter->first << " Age: " << counter->second->getAge() << endl;
    }
    else if (counter->first != personToBeFound)
    {
      cout << "Error 404, person does not exist..." << endl;
    }
  }
}

// Experimental....
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int menuChoice = -1;

  while (menuChoice != 0)
  {
    cout << "\nPlease enter: "
            "\n1 - to add a person "
            "\n2 - to find a person"
            "\n0 - to quit\n" << endl;
    cin >> menuChoice;
    switch(menuChoice)
    {
      case 1: add();
        break;
      case 2: find();
        break;
      case 0: menuChoice = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

### HEADER FILE:

```
#ifndef PERSON_H
#define PERSON_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Person {
 public:
  // Constructors

  /**
   * Create a Person with the given name and age.
   *
   * @param name name of the person
   * @param age age of the person - defaults to 0
   */
  Person(const std::string& name, unsigned short age = 0);


  // No explicit destructor necessary


  // Mutators

  /**
   * Set the name attribute
   *
   * @param name name of the person
   */
  void setName(const std::string& name);

  /**
   * Set the age attribute
   *
   * @param age age of the person
   */
  void setAge(unsigned short age);

  /**
   * Increment the age attribute
   */
  void growOlder();

  /**
   * Add a person to our list of children
   *
   * @param child Person to add as a child
   */
  void addChild(const Person& child);


  // Accessors

  /**
   * @return the Person's name
   */
  const std::string& getName() const;

  /**
   * @return the Person's age
   */
  unsigned short getAge() const;

  /**
   * @return a list of this Person's children
   */
  const std::vector<const Person *>& getChildren() const;

  /**
   * Define the ostream's << operator as a friend of this class
   * to allow this object to be printed to an output stream
   *
   * @param output the stream to print to
   * @param p the Person to print
   *
   * @return the output stream printed to
   */
  friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& output, const Person& p);


 private:

  // 0-arg Constructor
  Person();

  // Private attributes
  std::string _name;
  unsigned short _age;
  std::vector<const Person *> _children;

}; // Person

#endif
```

#### METHOD DEFINITIONS:

```
#include "Person.h"

Person::Person(const std::string& name, unsigned short age) :
    _name(name) , _age(age) {
}


void Person::setName(const std::string& name) {
  _name = name;
}


void Person::setAge(unsigned short age) {
  _age = age;
}


void Person::growOlder() {
  _age++;
}


void Person::addChild(const Person& child) {
  _children.push_back(&child);
}


const std::string& Person::getName() const {
  return _name;
}


unsigned short Person::getAge() const {
  return _age;
}


const std::vector<const Person *>& Person::getChildren() const {
  return _children;
}


std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& output, const Person& aPerson) {
  // Print our attributes to the output stream
  return output << "Name: '" << aPerson._name << "', Age: " << aPerson._age;
}
```

Comment: You're storing a pointer to a local variable in your map, so when you try to access it later the object that was pointed to has been destroyed (when `add` returns).

Comment: Looking a bit higher-level, you should probably be storing *value-types* and not pointers in your data containers -  e.g. `class Person`.  

The map would become std::multimap<std::string, Person>.

Comment: Critique #2:  The benefit of using a `std::multimap` over a `std::vector` is that searches by the key have `O(log(n))` time complexity.  By iterating over the map, it takes 'O(n)` - explore std::multi_map::equal_range()

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm That helps significantly, but  would like to understand why that is and best practices on how to counter this issue in the future. Logically, the map is accepting a pointer to a person object. Why is it that when I create a an actual pointer and point to to a person object then feed it into the map that it breaks? Thank you for taking the time to comment initially! I appreciate it!

Comment: The best practice is not to have a container of pointers if you can help it. If you can't avoid pointers, use `std::unique_ptr<Person>` not `Person *`.

Comment: Aside: you have a map of `Person`s keyed by name, and a `setName` function. What do you expect to happen if you rename someone?

Comment: @Caleth If you rename someone, the name inside the object will also change. This is just a simple book assignment we are doing in class to familiarize ourselves with C++, I am not new to programming but C++ is very interesting as it introduces those pesky pointers.

Comment: But where will they be in the map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi the comment of @1201ProgramAlarm is absolutely right, however, I thought by myself, how would I go about "rescuing" the program (a) with minimal effort, (b) to get a correct version and (c) very much in terms of the original version.

So here's a new `main.cc` version (`Person.h`, `Person.cc` needn't be changed):

```
#include "Person.h"
#include <map>

using namespace std;

multimap <string, Person *> personMap;
multimap <string, Person *>::iterator counter;


void add()
{
    string name;
    int    age;

    cout << "Please enter the name of the person: ", cin >> name;
    cout << "Please enter the age  of the person: ", cin >> age;

    personMap.insert({ name, new Person(name, age) });
}


void find()
{
    string personToBeFound;

    cout << "Who do you wish to find, friend: ", cin >> personToBeFound;

    for (counter = personMap.begin(); counter != personMap.end(); counter++)
    {
        if (counter->first == personToBeFound)
        {
            cout << "\nName: " << counter->first
                 <<   " Age: " << counter->second->getAge() << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Error 404, person does not exist..." << endl;
        }
    }
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int    menuChoice = -1;
    while (menuChoice != 0)
    {
        cout << "\nPlease enter: "
            "\n1 - to add a person "
            "\n2 - to find a person"
            "\n0 - to quit\n" << endl;

        cin >> menuChoice;
        switch(menuChoice)
        {
        case 1:
            add();
            break;

        case 2:
            find();
            break;

        case 0:
            menuChoice = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    // -- How to go about clearing the heap? --

    for (counter = personMap.begin(); counter != personMap.end(); counter++)
    {
        if (counter->second) {
            delete   counter->second;
            counter->second = nullptr;
        }
    }
}
```

I compiled using `g++ -o main Person.cc main.cc`. Regards, M.

**Update after this question**:

Why shouldn't I just delete the keys instead of just the values of the `multimap <string, Person *>` entries?

**Answer**:

I just wanted to show what could be done to prevent **orphaned** `Person` objects on the heap when the `multimap` went out of (local) scope and would thus be destroyed automatically by the `C++` system. More specifically:

(a) As in `C`, what is `malloc`-ed needs to be `free`-ed again later, the equivalent is true in `C++`: what is `new`-ed needs to be `delete`-ed later. This is best practice to prevent memory leaks in the long run.

(b) Now, back to our `multimap <string, Person *>`. Here, the keys are `string`s and the values are pointers to `Person` objects. These `Person` **pointers** are the only way left to get a hold on the corresponding `Person` **objects** allocated on the heap in calls to the `add()` function.

(c) In our case, the whole program is going to stop anyway after the `multimap` gets destroyed automatically, so `delete`-ing the `Person` objects using that extra `for`-loop isn't as important here, because `Person` objects remaining on the heap are garbage-collected by the operating system after the corresponding process has terminated, anyway.

Comment: Your answer makes sense in the fixed add() method so thank you for that. Could you please explain why I shouldn't just delete the key instead of just the value. It's okay if I delete duplicates along the way. Wouldn't just deleting the key be fine instead of nulling the value of the key? @micha

Comment: Wow! Splendid answer and explanation! Thank you so much for taking the time to explain all of this!!! @micha

Comment: @XOR you're welcome, glad I could contribute something. BTW, you might want to get back to this Person demo when it comes to `std::shared_ptr <X>`, `std::unique_ptr <X>` which often is the way to go in `C++11`. It's in  `#include <memory>`.   Regards, M.